# Bigquery got the error. Syntax error: Illegal input character "\357"

Tags: google-bigquery, syntax-error

When I run a query in Biquery using the command line bq query and indicating a *text_file.sql* containing the query, I got this error. The query was working using the bigquery console (https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?xxxxxxxx). I chose UTF-8.

How should I handle this syntax error?

Comment: Could you show your command line you're using which gives the error? How are you passing in the file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please check file format is correct or not. because this issue is due file type other than UTF-8 LF in my case.

when i was change file format to UTF-8 it was running file for me.